# Is there a way to import "typings" globally in Visual Code rather than modifying each JS file.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Is there a way to avoid typing manually all the reference paths for typings in visual code ? May be a config file which points to all typings in the project, which can help us to avoid typing "reference" statements in each JS file.I don't want these "reference" statements to be part of source control.

Comment: check out the Yeoman package "angular-gulp" they have a nice setup that uses the bower name to find the typing files and bring them down and reference them. It needed a small modification for me so i could manually included packages since some did not match like angular-strap but it will be a good starting point for you... if you use gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use files of tsconfig.json,

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

> I use filesGlob with atom-typescript, I don't know if it works for VS
>   too. Please let me know

Comment: I will give it shot and let you know. For the moment , I am switching over to Webstrom, makes my life easy.